# Measuring time taken by an exec()-ed process on linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I'm using the times() function to measure the value but I'm not sure if my approach is correct. Please have a look and advice

```
struct tms tms_start, tms_end;
if (!(pid=fork()))
{
    //some necessary operations here
    times(&tms_start);
    execl(...);
}
else if (pid)
{
    //in parent
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    times(&tms_end);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        if(WEXITSTATUS(status)==0)
        {
            clock_t real = tms_end.tms_cstime - tms_start.tms_stime
            float running_time = real/(double)sysconf(_SC_CLK_TK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to call `times(&tms_start)` before the call to `fork()`. In your code above, the `tms_start` variable is uninitialised in the parent since the parent never calls `times(&tms_start)`.

```
struct tms tms_start, tms_end;
times(&tms_start);             // <-- here
if (!(pid=fork()))
{
    //some necessary operations here
    execl(...);
}
else if (pid)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Ah I see. So this difference calculation is correct I guess?    clock_t real = tms_end.tms_cstime - tms_start.tms_stime

Comment: If you want to measure the time taken by the kernel on behalf of the child process, then your expression is correct. However if (more likely) you want to measure the CPU time taken by the process itself, then use tms_cutime and tms_utime. Or, if you want to measure the actual wall-clock time taken, don't use times() at all and instead use time() or gettimeofday().

Comment: and where does stop go?